# while cycle malfunctioning with div value

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason instead of taking the normal balance (1000-950) it goes from 1000 to 0 with the while cycle. I didn't want the refBalance to be less than 0. (numDebit2() return 50)

```
       <div class="elements" id="txtbalance">1000</div>
       <div class="elements" id="txtdebit">0</div>          
       <button class="button1" id="buttonNewHand" onclick="drawFaceTot()">new<br>hand</button>

        refDebit = document.getElementById("txtdebit");
        refBalance = document.getElementById("txtbalance");

      
        function numBalance(debit){
        
            
            var nBalance = parseInt(refBalance.innerText, 10);
            
            nBalance = nBalance - debit;
            
            refBalance.innerHTML = nBalance;
            
        
        }

        //I didn't want the refBalance to be less than 0.

        function drawFaceTot(){
            
            while (refBalance.innerHTML > 0) {

                numBalance(numDebit2());

            }   

        }
```

Comment: Please include a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), a precise definition of what you are doing, the expected output and the error you see in the actual output.

Comment: As far as I can see you call `numBalance` in a loop, which subtracts 50 from the text of `refBalance` until it is 0 or smaller than 0 (aka while it is bigger than 0). So in the end you see a 0.

Comment: Oh, I see. I supposedly wanted to remove 50 each time I press the button once and the balance doesn't go down from zero. This seems simple but I am not seeing a way to achieve it.

Comment: I managed to find a way to solve the problem. Thanks Barthy for the answer

Comment: Alright, glad I could help. I provided an answer based on what I understand. Even if you have found a solution it might help. In my answer you can also see an example of minimal and runnable code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably confusing a loop (`while`) with a one-off condition `if`.
Here's an example to only subtract the debit from the balance if the balance is positive:

```js
const refBalance = document.getElementById("txtbalance");

function numDebit2() {
  // do something here
  // returns 50 as per the question description
  return 50;
}

function numBalance(debit) {
  const nBalance = parseInt(refBalance.innerText, 10);
  refBalance.innerHTML = nBalance - debit;
}

function drawFaceTot() {
  if (refBalance.innerHTML > 0) {
    numBalance(numDebit2());
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="elements" id="txtbalance">1000</div>
<button class="button1" id="buttonNewHand" onclick="drawFaceTot()">new<br>hand</button>
```

*Note that this doesn't check if the debit is greater than the balance, so you could still end up with a negative balance.*